# How make spring transaction atomic

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence, spring-transactions

I need to persist some entities in database atomically, but I'm having some difficulties...
I have 4 entities: Emitente, NotaFiscal, Item and Duplicata.
Entities Item and Duplicata depends on NotaFiscal that depends on Emitente.
So, my dao classes try persist Emitente then NotaFiscal then Duplicata and finally Item.
But when I try to persist NotaFiscal I receive an error saying that Emitente doesn't exists.
These same entities was persisted correctly using entityManager.getTransaction().begin(); approach when this program was a desktop...

This is the class that call all Dao classes:

```
public class ControladorArmazenamentoNFeCompleta extends BaseDao implements
    IControladorArmazenamentoNotaFiscalCompleta {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private IControladorArmazenamentoNFe armazenadorNFe;
private IControladorArmazenamentoElementoNFe<Item> armazenadorItem;
private IControladorArmazenamentoEmitente armazenadorEmitente;
private IControladorArmazenamentoElementoNFe<Duplicata> armazenadorDuplicata;
private String mensagemErro;

public ControladorArmazenamentoNFeCompleta(
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    super(entityManagerFactory);
}

public StatusArmazenamento criar(NotaFiscal bean) {
    if (armazenarEmitente(bean)) {
            if (armazenadorNFe.recuperarPelaChave(bean.getId()) == null) {
                if (armazenadorNFe.criar(bean)) {
                    if (armazenarDuplicatas(bean)) {
                        if (armazenarItens(bean)) {                             
                            return StatusArmazenamento.SUCESSO;
                        } else {
                            mensagemErro = armazenadorItem
                                    .getMensagemErro();
                        }
                    } else {
                        mensagemErro = armazenadorDuplicata
                                .getMensagemErro();
                    }
                } else {
                    mensagemErro = armazenadorNFe.getMensagemErro();
                }
            } else {
                mensagemErro = "A nota fiscal já foi importada!";
                return StatusArmazenamento.IMPORTADA_ANTERIORMENTE;
            }
        }
    return StatusArmazenamento.ERRO;
}

private boolean armazenarEmitente(NotaFiscal bean) {
    if (armazenadorEmitente.recuperarPeloId(bean.getEmitente()
            .getNumeroCadastroNacional()) == null) {
        if (!armazenadorEmitente.criar(bean.getEmitente())) {
            mensagemErro = armazenadorEmitente.getMensagemErro();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean armazenarDuplicatas(NotaFiscal notaFiscal) {
    armazenadorDuplicata.setChaveNotaFiscal(notaFiscal.getId());
    Cobranca cobranca = notaFiscal.getCobranca();
    if (cobranca != null) {
        for (Duplicata duplicata : cobranca.getListaDeDuplicatas()) {
            if (!armazenadorDuplicata.criar(duplicata))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean armazenarItens(NotaFiscal notaFiscal) {
    armazenadorItem.setChaveNotaFiscal(notaFiscal.getId());
    if (notaFiscal.getListaDeItens() == null)
        return false;
    for (Item item : notaFiscal.getListaDeItens()) {
        if (!armazenadorItem.criar(item))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is the spring configuration:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<tx:advice id="txDao">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="recuperar*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="criar" rollback-for="PreexistingEntityException,Exception"/>
        <tx:method name="editar"
            rollback-for="IllegalOrphanException,NonexistentEntityException,Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:advice id="txControlador">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="criar" rollback-for="Exception"/>
        <tx:method name="atualizar" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="operacoesDao"
        expression="execution(* com.hrgi.persistencia.dao.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="operacoesCadastroDao"
        expression="execution(* com.hrgi.persistencia.cadastro.dao.interfaces.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="operacoesBancoDao"
        expression="execution(* com.hrgi.persistencia.banco.dao.interfaces.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="operacoesNFeDao"
        expression="execution(* com.hrgi.persistencia.nfe.dao.interfaces.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="operacoesControladorArmazenamento"
        expression="execution(* com.hrgi.persistencia.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:pointcut id="operacoesControladorArmazenamentoNFe"
        expression="execution(* com.hrgi.persistencia.nfe.controladores.interfaces.*.*(..))" />

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txDao" pointcut-ref="operacoesDao" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txDao" pointcut-ref="operacoesCadastroDao" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txDao" pointcut-ref="operacoesBancoDao" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txDao" pointcut-ref="operacoesNFeDao" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txControlador"
        pointcut-ref="operacoesControladorArmazenamento" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txControlador"
        pointcut-ref="operacoesControladorArmazenamentoNFe" />
</aop:config>
```

what could I do to solve it??

Comment: Try to reimplement it in English, because it's very hard to understand as it is. And it's supposed to be JPA code, but there is no call to any entity manager, so we can't even know what all those methods do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem simply changing propagation:

```
<tx:advice id="txDao">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="recuperar*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="criar" rollback-for="PreexistingEntityException,Exception"
            propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="editar"
            rollback-for="IllegalOrphanException,NonexistentEntityException,Exception"
            propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:advice id="txControlador">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="criar" rollback-for="Exception"
            propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
        <tx:method name="atualizar" rollback-for="Exception"
            propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Thanks for your attention.